# Difference in 2 Databases, saving the different lines

Tags: php, mysql, diff

I have 2 tables with the same structure.
Now one of them is an old dump of the live table.

I need to extract every line which is different or new in the live table compared to the old dump.

I know how to do this with a select on every row and then diff it with PHP, but this wouldn't be a effective solution.

Has anybody an Idea how I can make this in an easier way ?

Comment: Couldn't you import the rows from your old table that doesn't have a corresponding primary key in the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT newtable.*
FROM newtable LEFT JOIN oldtable USING (id)
WHERE oldtable.id IS NULL /* new rows */
OR newtable.col1 != oldtable.col1
OR newtable.col2 != oldtable.col2
OR newtable.col3 != oldtable.col3
...
```

Comment: if `oldtable.id` declare as `not null`

Comment: In a LEFT JOIN, everything in an unmatched row is NULL.